# Where can I get a complete list of Laravel events (fired by the core libraries)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I want to know what events are fired by Laravel core libraries. I want to get the complete list, such as `laravel.query` and `laravel.done`.

There are four events listed at [the official docs](http://laravel.com/docs/events#laravel-events), but I think Laravel has more events than these four!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Laravel doesn't actually fire as many events as you'd think. While it does make use of the Event system it's there for developers to use within there applications. Anyway, here's a list I compiled.

```
laravel.done
laravel.log
laravel.query
laravel.resolving
laravel.composing: {viewname}
laravel.started: {bundlename}
laravel.controller.factory
laravel.config.loader
laravel.language.loader
laravel.view.loader
laravel.view.engine

view.filter

eloquent.saving
eloquent.updated
eloquent.created
eloquent.saved
eloquent.deleting
eloquent.deleted
eloquent.booted: {$model}
eloquent.booting: {$model}


500
404
```

The `500` and `404` are both error related events. These are set in the `routes.php` file so you can see what the default listener is.

I'd like to point out that the `eloquent.{event}` have another variation containing the class name that is being updated.

```
eloquent.{event}: {classname}
```

I'm not going to say this is absolutely everything but it should be at least 99% of it.

Comment: It's worth noting that as of 5.4, some of the above have either been renamed or removed. I was looking for something similar to the `laravel.done` event but struggled to find any documentation. I recommend just listening out for all events with `*` and logging the event dispatcher instance passed in to get a feel for what's available.

Answer (score 19):

In addition to Jason Lewis answer, I have few more to add. I simply searched for `fire()` function and came up with following list for Laravel 5,

```
$this->events->fire('auth.attempt', $payload);
$this->events->fire('auth.login', [$user, $remember]);
$this->events->fire('auth.logout', [$user]);
$this->events->fire('cache.'.$event, $payload);
$this->laravel['events']->fire('cache:clearing', [$storeName]);
$this->laravel['events']->fire('cache:cleared', [$storeName]);
$events->fire('artisan.start', [$this]);
$this->events->fire('illuminate.query', array($query, $bindings, $time, $this->getName()));
$this->events->fire('connection.'.$this->getName().'.'.$event, $this);
$this['events']->fire('bootstrapping: '.$bootstrapper, [$this]);
$this['events']->fire('bootstrapped: '.$bootstrapper, [$this]);
$this['events']->fire('locale.changed', array($locale));
$this['events']->fire($class = get_class($provider), array($provider));  //after provider registered.
$this->app['events']->fire('kernel.handled', [$request, $response]);
$this->dispatcher->fire('illuminate.log', compact('level', 'message', 'context'));
$this->events->fire('mailer.sending', array($message));
$this->events->fire('illuminate.queue.failed', array($connection, $job, $data));
$this->events->fire('illuminate.queue.stopping');
$this->events->fire('router.matched', [$route, $request]);
$this->events->fire('composing: '.$view->getName(), array($view));
$this->events->fire('creating: '.$view->getName(), array($view));
```

Comment: Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending

Answer (score 5):

If you are debugging your Laravel application, you can get a full list of fired events in the console (for example when you are running unit tests or an artisan command) for the running process with the following snippet:

```php
Event::listen('*', function ($event) {
    echo $event."\n";
});
```

If you use the `logger` function it would go to an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few of them more, got them while dumping `static::$events`

```
laravel.config.loader
laravel.view.loader
laravel.language.loader
laravel.view.engine
404
```

Not really sure if overriding these would work, as they are internally called

Comment: You can actually listen for these and define your own custom loaders. This is great if you want a cascading loading system for configuration/view/language files. I've done this occasionally.