# laravel model callbacks after save, before save, etc

Tags: php, laravel

Are there callbacks in Laravel like:

```
afterSave()
beforeSave()
etc
```

I searched but found nothing. If there are no such things - what is best way to implement it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, Laravel has real callback before|after save|update|create some model. check this:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/3.0/laravel/database/eloquent/model.php#L362

the EventListener like saved and saving are the real callbacks

```
$this->fire_event('saving'); 

$this->fire_event('saved');
```

how can we work with that? just assign it to this eventListener example:

```
 \Laravel\Event::listen('eloquent.saving: User', function($user){
  $user->saving();//your event or model function
});
```

Comment: This is no longer the best answer with Laravel 4.  http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-events

Comment: The most complete documentation explaining Model Events is found in the master documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#events

Answer (score 76):

The best way to achieve before and after save callbacks in to extend the **`save()`** function.

Here's a quick example

```
class Page extends Eloquent {

   public function save(array $options = [])
   {
      // before save code 
      parent::save($options);
      // after save code
   }
}
```

So now when you save a Page object its **`save()`** function get called which includes the **`parent::save()`** function;

```
$page = new Page;
$page->title = 'My Title';
$page->save();
```

Comment: This is the best solution for making it function like CakePHP's afterSave() and beforeSave(). Alternatively, there are event hooks in the save() method if you want to apply it globally.

Comment: you need to be very careful here as you are not operating within a database transaction. parent::save(); completes a database transition. If you are saving before and after, they will also be complete transactions. If you need to make sure all saves happen or fail, then you need to wrap them in a DB::transaction().

Comment: the best way to do that in Laravel 4 is to user observer: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events

Comment: save() is called for edit and create ? how I can detect if save or edit ?

Comment: @fico7489 check is the `$model->id` is set. If it does you're editing.

Comment: How could I access the model's attribute, because I'll format them before saving

Comment: how to get any data or id here?

Comment: Please note that the `save` function returns a boolean. The code here does not pass that on!

Comment: @MartenKoetsier what version of laravel?

Comment: At least 5.7, perhaps 5.5 or even earlier (I cannot look that up right now)

Answer (score 28):

Adding in an example for Laravel 4:

```
class Page extends Eloquent {

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function($page)
        {
            // do stuff
        });

        static::updating(function($page)
        {
            // do stuff
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I spent some time wondering why the above doesn't work in my tests. There's a discussion about that here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1181. You can put the binding in global.php to fix the issue.

Answer (score 7):

Even though this question has already been marked 'accepted' - I'm adding a new updated answer for Laravel 4.

[Beta 4 of Laravel 4 has just introduced hook events for Eloquent save events](https://github.com/laravel/framework) - so you dont need to extend the core anymore:

> Added Model::creating(Closure) and Model::updating(Closure) methods for hooking into Eloquent save events. Thank Phil Sturgeon for finally pressuring me into doing this... :)

Answer (score 5):

In Laravel 5.7, you can create a model observer from the command line like this:

```
php artisan make:observer ClientObserver --model=Client
```

Then in your app\AppServiceProvider tell the boot method the model to observe and the class name of the observer.

```
use App\Client;
use App\Observers\ClientObserver;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
   {
        Client::observe(ClientObserver::class);
   }
   ...
}
```

Then in your app\Observers\ you should find the observer you created above, in this case ClientObserver, already filled with the created/updated/deleted event hooks for you to fill in with your logic.  My ClientObserver:

```
namespace App\Observers;

use App\Client;

class ClientObserver
{

    public function created(Client $client)
    {
        // do your after-model-creation logic here
    }
    ...
}
```

I really like the simplicity of this way of doing it.  Reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#events

Comment: Thanks! You are a live safer for me! This is the right answer when you are using 5.7

Answer (score 1):

Your app can break using afarazit solution*
Here's the fixed working version:

NOTE: `saving` or any other event won't work when you use eloquent outside of laravel, unless you require the events package and boot the events. This solution will work always.

```php
class Page extends Eloquent {

   public function save(array $options = [])
   {
      // before save code 
      $result = parent::save($options); // returns boolean
      // after save code
      return $result; // do not ignore it eloquent calculates this value and returns this, not just to ignore

   }
}
```

So now when you save a Page object its **`save()`** function get called which includes the **`parent::save()`** function;

```php
$page = new Page;
$page->title = 'My Title';
if($page->save()){
  echo 'Page saved';
}
```

afarazit* I tried to edit his answer but didn't work

Comment: actually no need to override the default, u can use the saving event to attach any pre-logic https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/f7caed6baa6856a4707f13e8eb25fd2f6e4f1e35/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L647-L649

Comment: "saving" or any other event won't work when you use eloquent outside of laravel, unless you require the events package and boot the events. This solution will work always.

Comment: oh okay, thanx for the headsup

Answer (score 0):

If you want control over the model itself, you can override the save function and put your code before or after `__parent::save()`.

Otherwise, there is an event fired by each Eloquent model before it saves itself.

There are also two events fired when Eloquent saves a model.

"eloquent.saving: model_name" or "eloquent.saved: model_name".

http://laravel.com/docs/events#listening-to-events

Comment: A complete list of event you can use, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059744/where-can-i-get-a-complete-list-of-laravel-events-fired-by-the-core-libaries