# How to access model attribute from an overrided eloquent save() method? (converting empty input to null)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

After using the code provided in the following comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/13518727/3159370 , I would like to access model attributes and change them before the model gets saved.

If you're curious why I want to do that, I think it's the best way to convert empty(varchar) 0(integer) to null before saving it in the database.

EDIT: What am looking for is a generic method to loop through all the attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access it using $this:

```
class Page extends Eloquent {

   public function save()
   {
      $this->sanitize();

      parent::save();
   }

   public function sanitize()
   {
      foreach($this->getAttributes() as $key => $value)
      {
         if ( ! $value)
         {
             $this->{$key} = null;
         }
      }   
   }
}
```

This is untested code, but should work.

Comment: Is this a generic function that loops through all the saved attributes? or just the 'name' attribute?

Comment: It wasn't, but it is now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in theory it should I guess, it accepts only save with the options array i ended up using :

`public function save(array $options = array())
 {
      $this->sanitize()

      parent::save($options);
   }`

but getting unkown error this time: 
`{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"syntax error, unexpected 'parent' (T_STRING)","file":"D:\\Laravel Mecscomp\\app\\models\\BaseModel.php","line":8}}`

Comment: It's just a missing `;` on `$this->sanitize();` !

Comment: Sorry, my bad, tested and working, thanks alot.
It still needs the options array as parameter.