# Laravel: Listen for Model save or update (after or before they're done)

Tags: laravel, save, updates

I need to generate a function to call after or before save() or update() but i don't know how to do.
I think I need a callback from save() update() but I don't know how to do.
Thanks

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518674/laravel-model-callbacks-after-save-before-save-etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel model callbacks after save, before save, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518674/laravel-model-callbacks-after-save-before-save-etc)

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Inside your model, you can add a **boot()** method which will allow you to manage these events.

For example, having User.php model:

```
class User extends Model 
{

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::creating(function($model){
            // ... code here
        });

        self::created(function($model){
            // ... code here
        });

        self::updating(function($model){
            // ... code here
        });

        self::updated(function($model){
            // ... code here
        });

        self::deleting(function($model){
            // ... code here
        });

        self::deleted(function($model){
            // ... code here
        });
    }

}
```

You can review all available events over here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events

Comment: Be aware: "When issuing a mass update via Eloquent, the saved and updated model events will not be fired for the updated models. This is because the models are never actually retrieved when issuing a mass update."
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events

Comment: You're absolutely right. This is only when running single requests, when working with batches I recommend to loop through the batch in case you need these events triggered.

Comment: A quick useful additional note @MauroCasas : You better use booted method instead of boot.

This method stands for this specific situation and called right after boot().

Doing so, you don't need to call parent::boot()

Comment: there are also `saving` and `saved`, that dispatch  on both update and create

Answer (score 36):

**This only works after an event happened on your model.**

## Method 1, using Observers

Create an observer for your model

```
php artisan make:observer UserObserver --model=User
```

this will create an event observer on your model

```php
class UserObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the User "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(User $user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the User "updated" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function updated(User $user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the User "deleted" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleted(User $user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the User "forceDeleted" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function forceDeleted(User $user)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

You must register this observer in the boot method on one of your ServiceProviders preferably the AppServiceProvider

```
// App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php

public function boot()
{
    User::observe(UserObserver::class);
}
```

## Method 2, using Closures

You can register custom events in the static booted method of your model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::created(function ($user) {
            //
        });
    }
}
```

**Available observable events**

```
// Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns

/**
 * Get the observable event names.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getObservableEvents()
{
    return array_merge(
        [
            'retrieved', 'creating', 'created', 'updating', 'updated',
            'saving', 'saved', 'restoring', 'restored', 'replicating',
            'deleting', 'deleted', 'forceDeleted', 'trashed'
        ],
        $this->observables
    );
}
```

**Note from Laravel documentation**

> When issuing a mass update via Eloquent, the saving, saved, updating, and updated model events will not be fired for the updated models. This is because the models are never actually retrieved when issuing a mass update.

it means that no event will be fired when you do something like this (update users in database directly):

```
User::where(...)->update(['name' => "ABC"]);
```

you have to manually get each user from the database and update it to get the events to fire, which is really very bad for performance.

```
User::where(...)->each(function($user) {
   $user->update(['name' => "ABC"]);
});
```

DONT do this... unless you know the table has a fixed and small row numbers

Answer (score 17):

Create a provider by using this command

```
php artisan make:provider ProviderClassName
```

then define the callbacks for models in boot function

```php
Model::created(function($model){
  //Do you want to do
});
```

List of available callbacks:

```php
Model::creating(function($model){});
Model::updated(function($model){});
Model::updating(function($model){});
Model::deleted(function($model){});
Model::deleting(function($model){});
Model::saving(function($model){});
Model::saved(function($model){});
```

Comment: Also saving() and saved()

Comment: No need for a complete new ServiceProvider, you can use AppServiceProvider which is used for Application customization.

Comment: what is a difference when I add this function to register function instead of boot?

Comment: There is also `retrieved()`, `restoring()`, `restored()`, `replicating()` and `forceDeleted()`