# Laravel model attribute default value

Tags: php, laravel

I want to set a default value to an attribute before saving it to the database using Eloquent.

Each time a model is saved the hash is going to be a random string, so I really don't want to pass that everywhere I save the model.

```
Model::create(['hash' => str_random(20)]);
```

I would rather have it in the model like below.

```
public function setHashAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['hash'] = str_random(20);
}
```

But this code does not work unless I pass some value into the create method, defeating the purpose.

```
Model::create(['hash' => 'I have to exist']);
```

Brainstorming I imagine there is `some method` that I can hook into that gets called just before being persisted to the database where I can generate a random string and append it to the `hash` attribute. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685019/laravel-how-to-create-a-function-after-or-before-saveupdate

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Great, had this issue myself :)