# Saving nested relation in laravel elequent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables and three relationship,

first, award table,

[image: click to see award table structure]

Award criteria,

[image: click to see criteria table structure]

Here criteria table self joined,

When saving the award in database,

Now I am saving as follows,

```
$award->save();
foreach ($request->criterias as $key => $row) {
            $criteria = new AwardCriteria();
            $criteria->title = $row['title'];
            $criteria->mark = $row['mark'];
            $criteria->save();
            foreach ($row['sub_criterias'] as $row2) {
                $subCrt = new AwardCriteria();
                $subCriteria->award_id = $award->id;
                $subCriteria->award_criteria_id = $criteria->id;
                $subCrt->title = $row2['title'];
                $subCrt->mark = $row2['mark'];
                $subCrt->save();
            }
        }
```

I can do it this way also,

```
  $award->save();
  $award->criteria()->saveMany($criteria);
```

But here How can save sub critirea's? Can you please anyone suggest good method?

Answer (score -1):

You can actually listen for saving events on a model and trigger an action. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685019/laravel-how-to-create-a-function-after-or-before-saveupdate) has some good examples around that.