# laravel datatable take long time to load data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, performance, laravel-datatables

I am trying to display database table to laravel datatable using below code but laravel datatable taking long time to load data.
I have approx 700000 records in database. How to decrease time of load data?

**Code**

**web.php**

```
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

**HomeController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $campaigns = TonicData::select('campaign')->distinct()->get();

    if (request()->ajax()) {
        $data = \DB::table('tonic_data')
            ->whereNotNull('subid4')
            ->where('subid4', '!=', '')
            ->select('subid4')
            ->groupBy('subid4')
            ->selectRaw('sum(view) as sum_of_views, sum(term_view) as sum_of_term_views,
                sum(add_click) as sum_of_add_click, sum(revenue_usd) as sum_of_revenue,
                (sum(revenue_usd)/sum(view)*1000) as rpm')
            ->when((request()->has('selectedCampaign') && request()->get('selectedCampaign') != ''), function ($query) {
                $query->whereIn('campaign', request()->get('selectedCampaign'));
            })
            ->when((request()->has('selectedDateRange') && request()->get('selectedDateRange') != ''), function ($query) {
                $query->whereBetween('day_date', [request()->get('selectedDateRange')['fromDate'], request()->get('selectedDateRange')['toDate']]);
            });

        return DataTables::of($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->make();
    }

    return view('dashboard', compact('campaigns'));
}
```

**dashboard.blade.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#datatable').dataTable({
            responsive: true,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{{ route('home') }}',
            columns: [
                {data: 'DT_RowIndex', orderable: false, searchable: false},
                {data: 'subid4', name: 'subid4'},
                {data: 'sum_of_views', name: 'sum_of_views', searchable: false},
                {data: 'sum_of_term_views', name: 'sum_of_term_views', searchable: false},
                {data: 'sum_of_add_click', name: 'sum_of_add_click', searchable: false},
                {data: 'sum_of_revenue', name: 'sum_of_revenue', searchable: false},
                {data: 'rpm', name: 'rpm', searchable: false}
            ]
        });
   });
</script>
```

**sql code**

```
query 1:
select  count(*) as aggregate
    from ( SELECT  `subid4`,
                   sum(view) as sum_of_views,
                   sum(term_view) as sum_of_term_views,
                   sum(add_click) as sum_of_add_click,
                   sum(revenue_usd) as sum_of_revenue,
                   (sum(revenue_usd)/sum(view)*1000) as rpm
            from  `tonic_data`
            where  `subid4` is not null
              and  `subid4` != ?
            group by  `subid4`
         ) count_row_table

query 2: 
select  `subid4`, sum(view) as sum_of_views, sum(term_view) as sum_of_term_views,
        sum(add_click) as sum_of_add_click, sum(revenue_usd) as sum_of_revenue,
            (sum(revenue_usd)/sum(view)*1000) as rpm
    from  `tonic_data`
    where  `subid4` is not null
      and  `subid4` != ?
    group by  `subid4`
    limit  10 offset 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: apply indexing in db? have you?

Comment: yes i added indexing in all columns to db table.

Comment: 700 thousands of row are a lot... why not make your datatable with some kind of search functionality, or (i do not know laravel) can't you paginate the result? A lot of datatables offer some kind of fetching feature to not wait too much on data retrieve.

Comment: @Goikiu laravel datatable take data in pagination default.

Comment: I had same issue with yajra datatable when I reached 300k records. Then I made datatable draw with manual php code.

Comment: can you please give me some example code?

Comment: https://shareurcodes.com/blog/dataTables%20server-side%20processing%20in%20codeigniter datatable draw concept.

Comment: Because in yajra datatable it'll fetch the all record then gives you 10 records as limit so every time when you make request with datatable it'll fetch 700k records with yajra but if you make with manually then you may set limit as per 10,20,50 which from datatable.

Comment: can you try to run the following query:
`
$data = \DB::table('tonic_data')
            ->whereNotNull('subid4')
            ->where('subid4', '!=', '')
            ->select('subid4')
            ->groupBy('subid4')
            ->selectRaw('sum(view) as sum_of_views, sum(term_view) as sum_of_term_views,
                sum(add_click) as sum_of_add_click, sum(revenue_usd) as sum_of_revenue,
                (sum(revenue_usd)/sum(view)*1000) as rpm')
`
Maybe the when clause is causing the issue.

Comment: Show us the generated SQL code for the 'loading'.

Comment: @RickJames i added SQL code.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya when you have 700k data, it is not an good idea to use datatables as it loads entire data at once. Instead consider pagination, show data on selected filters etc.

Comment: @Butterfly datatable is not load entire data as you seen above second query it is using `limit 10`.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya How about the first query? i dont see any limit on your laravel statement?

Comment: @Butterfly yes in first query don't have any limit. as you said  use pagination but pagination also take time to load data.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya that query also selects the record from `tonic_data` table so obviously it gets all 700k record right?

Comment: @Butterfly yes right.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize the discussion, as your query try to get all 700k records at once, no wonder it takes a long time.

Al though you are showing only a limited number of records while rendering the page, technically query gets all records on page load itself.

**Action Required**

1. Minimize the below section:

`->selectRaw('sum(view) as sum_of_views, sum(term_view) as sum_of_term_views,
                sum(add_click) as sum_of_add_click, sum(revenue_usd) as sum_of_revenue,
                (sum(revenue_usd)/sum(view)*1000) as rpm')`

Instead of sum up all these values on the fly, maintain a separate table and store all these values when any record gets altered in the `tonic_data`. There are callback functions as per  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685019/laravel-how-to-create-a-function-after-or-before-saveupdate).

2. Instead of `datatables` use laravel pagination and sorting which will perform on server side that controls loading the huge data on page load.
3. try to implement date based or other possible filters.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Laravel is running the *same* query twice -- once to get a row count, once to get the first 10 rows.

Because of the `GROUP BY`, the `LIMIT 10` has little effect on the speed.  This is because it must gather lots of rows, then do the grouping, and only finally deliver 10 rows.

The first query (to get the count) could be simplified and greatly sped up by changing to

```
    select  count(DISTINCT subid4) as aggregate
        from  `tonic_data`
        where  `subid4` is not null
          and  `subid4` != ?
```

and having

```
    INDEX(subid4)
```

Or forego of the count (if Laravel lets you do that).

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tonic_data`; I may have further tips.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I suggest looking into your query performance and try to optimize your query.

Secondly jquery datatables plugin has a feature (named as pipeline) to cache number of pages to reduce ajax calls. So this way let's say on first request if you have cached 10 pages, then it won't make another request to server until the 11th page is accessed and this goes on.

So on client side your ajax will be updated to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#datatable').dataTable({
            responsive: true,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: $.fn.dataTable.pipeline({
                url: '{{ route('home') }}',
                pages: 20 // number of pages
            })
        });
   });
</script>
```

For more help on pipeline, please refer https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html