# How can I specify in Laravel Eloquent that my column cannot be null?

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

As per title: How can I specify that when trying to save my model (pushing it to the database) that certain columns cannot be null?

e.g. `protected $fillable = ['name', 'haircolor'];`

I know that I can use a `[Mutator][1]` but that doesn't work when creating a new object with form data as input, only for individual assingment.

I might use the [before save event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518674/laravel-model-callbacks-after-save-before-save-etc) but that also sounds kinda hacky.

So is there a way to define the constraints in an eloquent model? Or maybe if not, a best practice?

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to define the column as not nullable in migration class by removing [`->nullable()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#columns).

You also could create a wrapper for `create()` function, like:

```
public function checkAndCreate($data) {
    // Check if some columns are null and do something about this.
    ....

    return $this->create($data);
}
```

Comment: But how does this help runtime?

Comment: I agree that having the SQL table not nullable is best way to enforce it. Other than that I think `model::saving()` event is safest way to catch-all as it will be triggered every time the event is saving (not only when created).

Comment: They (we?) should add a special type of exception if the save fails because of constraints in eloquent. That way it's way nicer to handle. I can make it for my dbms (mysql) but general implementation would be awesome.