# Laravel 4: which events does it support / have?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I saw [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059744/where-can-i-get-a-complete-list-of-laravel-events-fired-by-the-core-libaries) about Laravel events, but they are for Laravel 3. I've tried all of them, but none of them work. Here's my code in `global.php`:

```
$event_names = array("laravel.done", "laravel.log", "laravel.query", "laravel.resolving", "laravel.composing", "laravel.started", "laravel.controller.factory", "laravel.config.loader", "laravel.language.loader", "laravel.view.loader", "laravel.view.engine", "view.filter", "eloquent.saving", "eloquent.updated", "eloquent.created", "eloquent.saved", "eloquent.deleting", "eloquent.deleted");
foreach ($event_names as $event_name) {
    echo "Listening to {$event_name}<br/>";
    Event::listen($event_name, function($event) {
        var_dump($event);
        exit;
    }); 
}
```

It just starts listening, but no events fire. I've tried firing them on my own using `Event::fire()` and it works, but obviously that's not what I want.

Answer (score 6):

I found this list in laravel wiki: http://wiki.laravel.io/Event_List_(Laravel_4)

Comment: The list is currently (22 Jan 2015) incomplete.  Trying to get an account to update it, but manual approval takes time.  I've compiled a (more) complete list already, if anyone is interested until then.  I'll try to comment here when I get the article updated.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the following events in Laravel 4 so far:

```
auth.login
auth.logout

artisan.start

illuminate.query
illuminate.log

eloquent.updating
eloquent.updated
eloquent.creating
eloquent.created

locale.changed

composing: {viewName}
```

I'll update this list as I find more

Comment: Hmmm, what about the IoC that is so prevalent in the docs, couldn't it handle different event implementations? And even if it's not possible, I think that the practical benefit of the application firing events far (!) outweighs the ideological cons.

Comment: Sorry - I've done some more investigating - check out my revised answer